# Get all the sessions 15 mins prior to start time

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, datetime, timezone

I'm trying to get all the session list who are going to start in 15 minutes. The problem is with client and server timezones and conversions. I've this code so far.

MySQL server is on a different machine and client (nodejs server) is running on another machine.

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM sessions 
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(?) BETWEEN SUBTIME(session.start, "0:15:0") AND session.start'

values = [Math.round(Date.now()/1000)] // convert milliseconds to seconds
```

Comment: Provided `session.start` was set the same way as you query it, you should get what you need. To be consistent application just  shouldn't use Mysql server clock at all. No `..set session.start= now()` or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm expecting something like this:

```
select s.*
from sessions s
where s.start >= now() and s.start <= date_add(now(), interval 15 minute);
```

One reason your query doesn't work is because `between` expects the first comparison value to be less than the second.

Comment: thanks for the query, the second problem is, mysql is running in a different timezone, how to make mysql run in Miami or califronia time zone, it has something to do with `timezone` connection string

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper . . . This also depends on how the times were stored in the database -- using local time or database time.

Comment: we saved as local time as per the exact time of the session, and using `"dateStrings": "true"` connecting setting for client display. i.e. no conversion